# Two finite groups are isomorphic if and only if their group algebras are isomorphic as Hopf algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, hopf-algebras

Is there a good textbook reference for the proof of:

> Two finite groups $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic as groups if and only if their group algebras over the same field $K$ are isomorphic as Hopf algebras?

Comment: What do you need the reference for? I am not sure I know a good reference, but I would also not find it odd to mention it without proof in a research paper, seeing as the proof is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Is this not true if the group algebras are only required to be isomorphic as rings?

Comment: @JairTaylor No, any two abelian groups of the same order will have isomorphic group algebras when only seen as algebras. But the Hopf-algebras can be distinguished.

Comment: @JairTaylor A less obvious one is if you consider the integral group algebras. I don't recall the answer in that case.

Comment: As rings the answer is no due to a counter-example of Martin Hertweck, see e.g https://zbmath.org/0990.20002?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'd be interested in seeing the proof if it is straightforward.

Comment: @Jair The main ingredient is showing that the set of group-like elements actually coincides with the group you started with. Once this is shown the result is clear. And showing it is essentially just computing the coproduct of an arbitrary element and comparing that to its tensor square.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I see, that makes sense, thanks!